# Adding viewable css list with members of a certain sp group

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, html

My end goal is to have users come in and easily remove certain users from certain groups. I want all members from the selected group to appear in a list which i have already created in css on button click. I am having trouble telling the program how to just select the one group. the code below is what I am messing with but I am getting an error saying that:

"Error2 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup' because 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

```
      public void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;           
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        groups = web.SiteGroups;
        SPGroup spGroup = web.SiteGroups[group];

        foreach (SPMember member in spGroup)
        {
            myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + member + "</a></li>";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many issues with your code:
Most obvious - in your loop you are missing ".Users" as in

```
foreach (SPUser usr in web.Groups["Zee-Group"].Users)
{
//do some work
}
```

I'm not sure i've understood the "css on button click" part - but I assume you have a list where you use some Person/Group field with only "User" being allowed, you would also need to use EnsureUser (as explain here http://blog.myitechnology.com/2009/06/right-way-to-spwebensureuser.html) and all this within a elevated (make sure the reference you receive for SPWeb is already called in "elevated" mode) sub-routing RunWithElevatedPrivileges  as otherwise it shall not properly execute the call if the current user does not have enough permissions.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Sorry about the confusion, let me be more clear. I am wanting to display a list of members based on what group is selected in my dropdownlist on button click. The list is made in css.              string group = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;             SPGroup spGroup = web.Groups[group];                  foreach (SPUser user in groupName)
            {
myList.InnerHtml += "<li><a href='#'>" + user + "</a></li>";
            }

Comment: I kind of feel like re-asking this question and making it more clear with my updates.